# Unable to build unity app - issue not clear

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

Need help when i am trying to build my unity project its giving below error.
But i could not rectify error due to same. Any help will be useful.

Error 1

```
Error: Failed to add D:\jbINTEG\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes.dex

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Error 2

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk. See the Console for details.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error: Failed to add D:\jbINTEG\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes.dex
]
stdout[

]
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Error 3

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk. See the Console for details.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error: Failed to add D:\jbINTEG\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes.dex
]
stdout[

]
```

Comment: Why are there mixed slashes and backslashes in your paths ? PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar

Comment: @FLX no idea about path being as above. Its coming as above in errors.
Need help to get it resolved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for thinking over to my question.

Got it working. Actually found issue.
Its related to antivirus in my machine. When i tried over building it for android platform. Kaspersky Antivrus was terminating packaging of apk via aapt tool.
So at the end above issue was coming over again and again.

As soon as i paused antivirus protection and rebuild unity project. Everything started working fine without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some issue with your android sdk. 
you should remove it and create a clean installation/setup of the android sdk also maybe reinstall java,jre & jdk